# Verbose display of a git add

Tags: git, debugging, addition

I have a file that shows up in `git status`'s `"Changed but not updated"` list as `(modified content, untracked content)`, and whose status doesn't change when I do `git add` on it.

I was wondering if there is a command that will give me more diagnostic information. The `-v` option didn't to anything.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure your file [isn't part of a submodule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4161022/git-how-to-track-untracked-content): adding a file of a submodule from its parent repo wouldn't work.

[`git status`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-status.html) can display changes to a submdodule, unless the `--ignore-submodules[=<when>]` is used. (or if the config `diff.ignoreSubmodules` is set).

Answer (score 2):

Check the response of `git ls-files --others --ignored --exclude-standard` to see if Git believes it should be ignored. This would be the first debugging step that I would take.

Then, you can try to force the addition with `git add --force <filename>` and see if that overcomes any ignoring that is preventing the addition to staging.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried looking at your .gitignore file in the project's root directory.  You may have the file in question excluded from tracking. Hope that helps -