# Can I add a sibling directory as a git submodule?

Tags: git

When I try doing this I get following error:

```
fatal: '../web' is outside repository
```

Answer (score 3):

You can, if that sibling directory is a git repo.

But it is best, [as in this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6106503/6309), to use the full path of that `web` folder.