# Git - Bitbucket repo hasnt stored the files in a sub-folder

Tags: git, file, bitbucket

I have a repo on Bitbucket. I just noticed, it has not stored a particular sub-folder I added later.

Upon noticing, I tried to run the commands:

```
git add *
```

(didnt add the sub-folder)

```
git add (folder path)
```

(still no affect)

My .gitignore is empty

How can I add the files to the repo?

On the repo, I have the directory & files showing as (i.e. the files are mere references, not clickable):

[image: snapshot of bitbucket where the files are only referenced not stored]

Comment: Did you try git push after adding?

Comment: yes I did. I checked the status, no changes reported. Tried commit, still nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your repo does not have a `.gitmodules` file, then those not-clickable references are **nested git repo** whose **[gitlink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309)** ([special entry in the index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2227598/6309)) is recorded by the git repo parent.

That allows the parent to record the SHA1 of those repos (but without recording from *where* those repos are coming from, as opposed to submodules, which keep their origin url in the `.gitmodules` file of the parent repo).

Check if `1507-MainApp` has a `.git/` sub-folder in it: that would make is a nested repo.

If you really want to consider the content of that folder as part of your repo (and discard its history), simply do a:

```
# no trailing slash: you need to remove the gitlink first
git rm --cached 1507-MainApp

rm -Rf 1507-MainApp/.git
git add 1507-MainApp
```

Then commit and push.

If you want to keep the history of those subfolder, [then you would need to add them as submodule](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6106503/6309).

Comment: Excellent point and yes, there were stored in another external folder and copied to this repo via file manager. However, I deleted the git file & folder. Yet still I cant add.

Comment: @Kayote I have edited my answer: you need to remove the gitlink, special entry, first. Then you can add

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your folders are submodules.

This is why they are not added.

:-)

[image]

as you can see a submodule has its own commit id since its a standalone project which is just "stored" inside root folder as the parent folder.

Comment: What does 'submodule' mean in git context? and How can I add them?

Comment: You cant add them, they are self contained sub repositories inside the root git project