Add a git submodule from zip file/unzipped folder
I'm having troubles to clone a submodule that I need (pytorch). So I just downloaded the zip file.
Now, I want to add that unzipped folder as a submodule to my repo.
Usually, I would do:
git submodule add [GIP REPO] [PATH_WHERE_I_WOULD LIKE TO PLACE IT]
Unfortunately, this does not work. Do you have any clues on how to solve this? Many thanks!

Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6100966/nested-git-repositories-without-remotes-a-k-a-git-submodule-without-remotes

I'm sorry. It did not.

As the title says, I'm assuming that the repository has been extracted from the zip file.
If you want to add a submodule, the correct syntax would be:
git submodule add <repository>

where <repository> can be either a URL or a path relative to the current repository.

<repository> is the URL of the new submodule’s origin repository. This may be either an absolute URL, or (if it begins with ./ or ../), the location relative to the superproject’s default remote repository.

If you supplied [GIT REPO] to specify a different name for the submodule, then you need to add the --name option. In your case, the command would look like this:
git submodule --name <git_repo> add <repository>

Furthermore, when a submodule's remote is referred with a path instead of a URL, Git may show the error message "Transmission type 'file' not allowed". This is because, by default, the protocol.file.allow option is disabled. In order to enable this configuration, you need to use the 'git config' command and set the option to always.
#enabling file transmission
git config --global protocol.file.allow always

