# Github - uploading files

Tags: github

I am trying to add a folder to a github repository. The file appears empty on github and has a green arrow on it. Does anyone know how to fix this problem? I would appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: Is the folder/directory empty? Git cannot store empty directories. So in that case it would be a limitation of Git itself, not a GitHub problem.

Comment: I think the problem is that the folder is being added as a submodule but i'm not sure how to fix that

Comment: ok problem fixed! I think the problem was that the folder seemed to belong to 2 repositories. I created a new folder and recopied the code from the old folder then added it on the repository. That fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This seems similar to the "[Git - how to track untracked content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4161022/git-how-to-track-untracked-content)", where a folder got added as a "gitlink":

> Effectively you are using the internal feature that git submodule uses (gitlink entries) but you are not using the submodule feature itself.

That is what is represented by a **green arrow in GitHub: a submodule**, as shown in the [GitHub submodule help page](http://help.github.com/submodules/):

[image: GitHub submodule]

What you did is essentially adding the submodule content in your Git repo.
You may want to check "[How do I remove a git submodule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260748/how-do-i-remove-a-git-submodule)" or "[un-submodule a git submodule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759587/un-submodule-a-git-submodule)" in order to be sure you got rid of any submodule reference.