# git submodule update --remote vs git pull

Tags: git, git-submodules

What is the difference between running

```
git submodule update --remote
```

vs

```
cd <submodule directoy>
git pull
```

Assuming that the submodule was previously set to track some branch:

```
git submodule add -b master [URL to Git repo]
```

Comment: it may be similar with 1 submodule, but imagine you have 5+

Answer (score 78, accepted):

The difference is:

- `git pull` will only update your submodule branch, but it can be any branch that you could have checked out yourself in that submodule repo.
- `git submodule update --remote` will only update the branch registered in the `.gitmodule`, and by default, you will end up with a detached HEAD, unless `--rebase` or `--merge` is specified or the key `submodule.$name.update` is set to `rebase`, `merge` or `none`.

In both cases, you still have to go back to the parent repo, add and commit the new submodule SHA1 reference.
That is because in both instances, the SHA1 of the submodule changes, which means the **[gitlink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309)** ([special entry in the index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19354410/6309) of the parent repo, named after to root folder of the submodule) must be added and committed.

A [`git submodule update --init --remote`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule#Documentation/git-submodule.txt-update--init--remote-N--no-fetch--no-recommend-shallow-f--force--checkout--rebase--merge--referenceltrepositorygt--depthltdepthgt--recursive--jobsltngt--no-single-branch--ltpathgt82308203) is like:

- [`git submodule init`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule#Documentation/git-submodule.txt-init--ltpathgt82308203): to initialize (checkout) the submodules recorded in the index
- [`git submodule update --remote`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule#Documentation/git-submodule.txt-update--init--remote-N--no-fetch--no-recommend-shallow-f--force--checkout--rebase--merge--referenceltrepositorygt--depthltdepthgt--recursive--jobsltngt--no-single-branch--ltpathgt82308203): to pull from the registered branch (or master by default), once the submodule has been initialized (checked out).

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by "add and commit the new submodule SHA1 reference"

Comment: @Doug That is because of the gitlink: I have edited the answer and added links which illustrate what a gitlink is. You can see a gitlink here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9857021/6309

Comment: Can this answer be more elaborate?
I am thinking specifically on the difference between --init and --remote flags.

Comment: @tortal 6+ years later, sure, I can expand on that answer. I have edited said answer: let me know if I can add more details to it.