# git clone --recursive - submodules on no branch

Tags: git, git-branch, git-submodules, git-clone

I have a git module called 'production' and inside a couple of submodules. When I use the following command: `git clone --recursive git@git_server:production` it's clonning the 'production' module with the submodules. When I `cd` in one of the submodule and give the following command: `git branch -a` I get:

```
* (no branch)
  master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master
```

The `.gitmodules` files contains:

```
[submodule "blabla"]
url = git@git_server:production/blabla
path = blabla
branch = refs/heads/master
...........................................
```

The question is: Why if I clone recursive the submodules are on the branch "(no branch)" and if I clone only the respective submodule is cloning directly on branch "master"? Is there any way to change the configuration that when I clone recursive to clone directly all the submodule in branch "master"?

Answer (score 1):

> Why if I clone recursive the submodules are on the branch "(no branch)"

The parent repo checkout the submodule directly on the SHA1 recorded by the **[gitlink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309)** ([special entry in the index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19354410/6309))

If you were to add a **`gitsubmodule update --recursive --remote`** (after your clone), then it would go ion the submodule, fetch and update the branch.

[See also the `submodule.$name.update` config](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19621245/6309).

Comment: Thanks for answer! Unfortunately, when I give this command `git submodule update --recursive --remote` is doing nothing. The problem is thant git submodule doesn't have `--remote` flag. I am using git version 1.7.1