# What is the difference between these two git commands to update latest submodules?

Tags: git, git-submodules

`git pull --recurse-submodules`

vs.

`git submodule update --recursive --remote`

I have seen these two been used in the same context when updating/pulling the latest submodules, but I can't find the difference between them and when to use which?

Comment: The 1st affects (pull) the whole repo and submodules. The 2nd updates only the submodules. Here is https://stackoverflow.com/a/19621245/418599 a similar question that can be tailored to yours.

Comment: Great! Could you add that as an answer?

Comment: Answer added, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 1st affects (pull) the whole repo and submodules. The 2nd updates only the submodules.

Here is https://stackoverflow.com/a/19621245/418599 a similar question that can be tailored to yours.