# Why isn't GIT tracking my cakephp migrations Plugin?

Tags: cakephp, plugins, migration, cakephp-2.0, cakedc

I am using GIT to deploy my cakephp applications, a few days ago I started using the migrations plugin (by cakeDC) in my app to simplify database versions and changes.

After installing the Migrations Plugin on my local development machine, I committed the changes and pushed it to my production server, and tried to run the migrations plugin from there. 
After looking at the server for quite some time I realized it had not grabbed all of the migrations plugin, however the following were changed:

app/Config/bootstrap.php had the following line appended 
CakePlugin::load('Migrations');

The Plugin folder now had a Migrations folder, but it was empty.

I resolved this by uploading the plugin via FTP.  I ran a git status on it and it shows the working directory clean...

Why isnt GIT tracking my Migrations plugin folder contents?

Comment: Post the contents of .gitignore

Comment: *.clpprj
log/*
tmp/*
git/*
.git

web/app/tmp/logs/*
web/app/tmp/sessions/*
web/app/tmp/tests/*
web/app/tmp/cache/models/*
web/app/tmp/cache/persistent/*
web/app/tmp/cache/views/*
!empty


web/stats/*
web/error/*
favicon.ico
cgi-bin/*
ssl/*

Comment: Answer:  The Plugin folder is not being tracked because it was installed as a submodule.

the very first instructions I found for installing the Plugin included making it a git submodule (which at the time I didn't know what that was...) I have determined that it was installed this way via this thread: Unable to track files within Git submodules

@Chris Herbert Thanks the response

I used this thread for the removal: How do I remove a git submodule?

and I hope this helps someone in the future as I had a heck of a time with it. Next time I'm going read about a command before using it.

Thanks!

Comment: It's not necessarily a bad idea to track the plugin as a submodule, but you will need be aware of it (ie, use "git clone --recursive", etc).

Comment: I always track my plugins as submodules. (With the new composer support coming this won't be necessary, but it's a great solution now.)

Comment: @CertifiedGeek Be sure to add your solution as an answer for other who might experience this issue.

Comment: @Chris Herbert - I agree it would probably be helpful but from what I read it seemed cumbersome to make sure its pulled everytime. I must've thought it would have to be updated everytime, but with "git clone --recursive" I'm thinking it would be easier to manage than I thought.

Comment: @jeremyharris thanks for the input,  I definitely think its a great concept

Comment: @DavidYell - thanks, I tried to add it but I had only been a user for 6 hours and it wouldnt let me answer my own question.    I guess I'm what they call a long time reader, first time poster... ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Plugin folder is not being tracked because GIT thought it was a submodule.

I ran into this issue because I used GIT to clone this Plugin into the plugin directory. and git didnt add it since it was a repository in itself.  When GIT didnt add it to my tracked files I did it manually: `git add app/Plugin/Migrations/`
this created a gitlink and essentially acted like a submodule, as seen in this thread:

[Git - how to track untracked content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4161022/git-how-to-track-untracked-content/4162672#4162672)

Since at the time I didnt want to use the plugin as a submodule, I corrected this issue with the following commands:

`git rm --cached app/Plugin/Migrations`

with a `git status` I could see that GIT was now recognizing my Plugin

I then could proceed with a `git add .` and `git commit -m "finally adding the plugin"`

I hope this helps someone in the future.

Thanks!