# Impossible to checkout Git code for Windows 8 via TortoiseGit or msysGit. Works fine with Ubuntu Git. "Submodules error"

Tags: php, git, git-submodules, gitignore, tortoisegit

My Setup:

**OS:** Windows 8 x64

**I use these VCS:**
msysgit
https://msysgit.github.io/

and TortoiseGit:
https://tortoisegit.org/

**Server:** Zend Server (LAMP) for Windows

So Git Checked-out around 60 MiB, the rest was Vendors stuff. So it just stuck. And did not checked out whole 300 MB

Erorr reported by "msysgit" (Windows Git+):

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe" clone -v --recurse-submodules --progress  "ssh://user@git.website.com:12345/REPOName" "C:/<...>/SiteName/REPOName"
Cloning into 'C:/...>/SiteName/REPOName'...
FATAL ERROR: Network error: Software caused connection abort
remote: Total 21679 (delta 13490), reused 21627 (delta 13490)[K
No submodule mapping found in .gitmodules for path 'main/src/vendor/assetic'
Done
'main/src/vendor/assetic'
Done
```

It is checking out OK all 300 MiB on Ubuntu 12 Server Edition with Git installed (apt-git)

But on Windows it stucks at 60 MiB with both **TortoiseGit** and **msysgit**. Is there is any way how I can skip 'submodules' to checkout, or to fix this issue.
Maybe I should add submodules to .gitignore?

## ***UPDATE:***

So there is no **<..>/ProjectName/REPOName/.gitmodules**
file, but there is a **<..>/ProjectName/REPOName/.git/config** file.

The content of .git/config is this (ant it works for Ubuntu's Git, but not Windows Git's):

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
    hideDotFiles = dotGitOnly
[remote "origin"]
    url = ssh://USER@git.SITENAME.com:12345/REPOName
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

Should I create a blank hidden ".gitmodules" file and should I try to copy-paste the content to that file, or anyone know what the content suppose to be of **.gitmodules**.

Comment: Do you have a `.gitmodules` file? or do you have your submodules stored in `.git/config` ?

Comment: I'm not sure. But I don't see a '.gitmodules' files. And there is '.git/config' file. Is that anwsers your question?

Comment: Are you actually using submodules? If you run `git submodule` on the Ubuntu box does it output anything? If so, is there a `.gitmodules` file there which hasn't been checked in?

Comment: cjc343, when I login via Filezilla to my Ubuntu VM, in the I only see that there is "REPOname/.git/config" file. I don't see "REPOname/.git/.gitmodules" file. We can checkout our git code to any Ubuntu Linux VM machine. Already tried on 3 Ununtu Linux/Server computers.

Comment: The file should be at `REPOname/.gitmodules` or a directory along the `REPOname/main/src/vendor/` path, not inside the `.git` directory. The `.git/config` file is different. Does `git submodule` on any of the Ubuntu boxes output anything when run in your repo?

Comment: Look into `git subtree`, won't fix your problem, but will prevent you from many more.

Comment: This answer may help you fix or debug what's going on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4161022/git-how-to-track-untracked-content/4162672#4162672

Answer (score 1):

Can you please checkout top level module without --recurse.

Is there a possibility that .submoudule file is committed on some other branch ?