# git push origin master creating empty directories in github

Tags: github, git-clone

I have cloned certain github repositories to my laptop. Now I want to push these local directories to my github .When I do "git push origin master" everything does smoothly. But if I have a look at my github repository I can only see empty directories getting created. All the directories are under the same directory .
The commands that I perform to update on github :
git add .
git commit -m ""
git push origin master

Following is a snapshot of my github view : [image: How I see empty directory folders in github]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the following and it worked :

git rm --cached Retrofit2SampleApp

git rm --cached ud851-Sunshine

rm -rf Retrofit2SampleApp/.git

rm -rf ud851-Sunshine/.git

git add Retrofit2SampleApp

git add ud851-Sunshine

git commit -m "commit after removing cache and .git inside the folders"

git push origin master

Got some clue from the following link : 
[Git - how to track untracked content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4161022/git-how-to-track-untracked-content)

Answer (score 0):

i think you havent added new files to repository

```
 1. git status
 2. git add -A
 3. git commit -am "your commit"
 4. git push origin master
```

try these i believe this will help yo

Comment: Hi Ankit , Thanks for your response !  I just tried the mentioned commands, but I see the same empty directories :(.