# Git modified content untracked content

Tags: git, github

I had some issues about pushing a local git repo to an existing remote git repo (Github). Git was complaining about a folder that was missing in my local repository but present in my remote repository, so I wasn't able to push on Github. As I had no idea about how to solve this problem I decided to delete both git repositories (local and remote) -- using [How to fully delete a git repository created with init?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1213430/how-to-fully-delete-a-git-repository-created-with-init) --, and create a new repository in my project directory to push it on Github.

Then I did `git init` and `git add .` and got this message in VS Code :
"The git repository at `/path` has too many active changes, only a subset of Git features will be enabled. Would you like to add 'node_modules' to .gitignore?" -- I did nothing about that.

Then when I enter `git status` in Terminal I had an unusual / huge amount of files (node_modules again) on stage except my src/pages folder which is displayed in red:

```
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
  (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)

modified:   src/pages (modified content, untracked content)"
```

So I did `git add src/pages` and after that I got back to the same problem.

Git also proposed me to use `git rm --cached <file>` to unstage but I don't know what that does once executed (I mean it doesn't work in my case).

It seems I created a kind of conflict by deleting and recreating my local git repository and I'm unable to figure out how to get things back to normal. I would like to be able to track the content of the src/pages of my App again and then push it on Github. Could anyone explain me what is happening under the hood? Thanks.

Note: I also tried this but it doesn't work for me : [How to fix "modified content, untracked content" in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50167969/how-to-fix-modified-content-untracked-content-in-git)

Comment: Your `src/pages` appears to be another Git repository. In your original Git repository, it was probably a *submodule*. Are you using the trick in which your GitHub pages is a submodule of the main repository? If so, do you want to keep using that trick?

Comment: @torek I dont't really know what is the difference between a Git repository and a submodule but I just checked my folder project. There is a .git at the root and another in the src/pages. About the trick you mentioned, at the moment there is no Github repository, I deleted it. For now I am stuck with the fact that I'm unable to commit my src/pages (the main content of my project) so I did not try to recreate a repository on Github. I'm unaware of that kind of trick and don't know the utility.

Comment: @torek So I guess I've got to remove the git repository in src/pages? And what about the fact that when I commit there is just all those node_modules on stage?

Comment: If src/pages is meant to be a submodule that is a copy of the main repository, you'll need to add it as a separate submodule using `git submodule add`. Each submodule is a Git repository in its own right—it has its own branches and commits. The tricky thing with pages that I have heard of (I have not done it myself) is that you use the same Git repository twice, once as the superproject, and once as the submodule. I have not set this up myself, so I'm not entirely sure what the method is.

Comment: @torek I deleted the submodule in my src/pages and was able to push on github. Thank you for your answers.