# Git thinks directory is file

Tags: windows, git

Git thinks that one of my directories on Windows is a file, but I want it to recognize the actual files inside and not the directory as a file.

```
$ git status
On branch main
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
  (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)
        modified:   public/js/phoneme-synthesis (untracked content)

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

```
$ git add .
```

(Nothing happens)

```
$ git restore .
```

(Nothing happens)

```
$ git commit -a
On branch main
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

```
$ git stash
No local changes to save
```

I have tried removing the .git folder altogether and reinstantiating the git repo. I also tried to gitignore the directory. I am expecting a directory to never be shown as changed, and I expect git to discover the files inside.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+modified+untracked+content

Comment: @phd While the answer is similar, the question is different. My question is about a directory that is shown as a modified file, while the linked question and also the search you linked is about a totally different thing, which is how to add modified untracked content that just can't be added. I refuse to accept that that is the same question.

Comment: Your `git status` showed "untracked content" which is well-known sign of the problem. Take the question https://stackoverflow.com/q/50167969/7976758 and its answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/59579206/7976758 if you prefer so,

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem after renaming the directory and then trying to re-add it. The directory itself contained a `.git` directory that I couldn't see. After deleting that, everything worked again.