# Git: How to commit untracked content?

Tags: git

Synopsis: git status gives

> Changes not staged for commit: 
> (use "git add ..." to update
>   what will be committed) 
> (use "git checkout -- ..." to discard
>   changes in working directory) 
> (commit or discard the untracked or
>   modified content in submodules)
>
> **modified:**    < folder name >      **(modified content, untracked content)**

In case:

- 'git add' does not change the situation
- You are looking for a way to **commit** the untracked content

What is the **right** way to fix that?

There is a related question here: [How to track untracked content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4161022/how-to-track-untracked-content), A simple answer to the common problem is hiding at the second, non accepted answer. Hope this thread would add clarity.

Comment: Do you have a question? Why did you created this question?

Comment: I would like to document that knowledge in public so that others can find it later, more easily: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: The error does tell you what to do.

Comment: @evolutionxbox, 'commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules' can be definitely further explained; this is exactly what this thread does.

Comment: Yes, but it's unclear as there are two other reasons why changes might not be staged for committing. Perhaps mention that specifically in the question?

Comment: Thanks @evolutionxbox, I edited the question, hope it is more clear now.

Comment: I answered a very similar question at https://stackoverflow.com/q/54907159/1256452

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A common reason for the problem:

An unrelated git repository (".git" folder) in a subfolder, prevents the main git repository from tracking the subfolder.

There are two possible solutions:

1) **Simple fix: using only the main repository** - delete the ".git" folder in the 'problematic' **subfolder** 
 Take care not to delete the .git folder of the main repository, if possible copy what you intend to delete locally as a backup - just in case 
[This idea had been suggested by @neoneye here [How to track untracked content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4161022/how-to-track-untracked-content) ]

2) **Using sub-module**:
Using git sub-module might be the solution you want. To get informed about this option you might find the related article https://medium.com/@porteneuve/mastering-git-submodules-34c65e940407 very useful.

Comment: I don't understand how this answers the question given.