# Unable to add folder to git repo

Tags: git, git-add

I think this issue has already been discussed under this question :

[Recursively add the entire folder to a repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17743549/recursively-add-the-entire-folder-to-a-repository)

However I still can not add some folders to a git repository and I need help.

```
$ git status
...
# modified:   folder_to_add1 (modified content, untracked content)
# modified:   folder_to_add2 (modified content, untracked content)
```

These folders originally belonged to another git repository, so I entered the folders and deleted the .git folder inside.

I then ran:

```
$ git add folder_to_add1
$ git add folder_to_add2
$ git status 
# On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#   (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#       ../filestore/
#       ../../stdout
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Neither folder_to_add1 and folder_to_add2 can be committed.

There is no .gitignore file in my repo.

What else can I try ? Thanks.

---

I will try to add further information regarding my original post which ended right before previous line. I will appreciate your comments regarding "this" being considered the right war to further clarify my original question, I am a complete newbie posting here.

Dear torek, thanks for your very detailed answer. I guess I will have to read it very carefully to understand the subtleties involved with the submodules concept. I guess submodules are very much like "svn externals" which I am more familiar with.

From a ten minutes reading of your answer, my answer is: "I do not want a submodule or subgit at all". I mean: I want these folders, originally being submodules, to be part of only one project instead of many projects (to use a figure).

I am sure your answer is somewhere telling me why this is happening, but the fact is that I need to copy my project from one PC to another one and by using git to do it, these folders are actually not included in the index with "git add " regardless of whether there is a .git subfolder in them or not.

A ".gitmodules" file does not seem to exist. After running :

```
$ find . -name .gitmodules -print
```

on the main folder of the project I get no results.

What I did to be able to add these folders to a new (different) repository was:

```
$ cp -r myproject /home/myusername/newproject
$ cd /home/myusername/newproject/folder_to_add1
$ rm -r .git
$ cd ../folder_to_add2
$ rm -r .git
$ cd /home/myusername/newproject
$ git init
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "Adding all existing files to the new repository"
```

But I think I loose all file changes history by doing it this way.

Comment: Is there anything in the folders?

Comment: Hi, Jose, welcome to SO. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54902890/git-how-to-commit-untracked-content) was asked today. And since it seems linked to submodules, answers might be [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4161022/how-to-track-untracked-content).

Comment: If the folders are empty ... try adding a dummy file, e.g., readme.txt and then try to commit the folders.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I add an empty directory to a Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115983/how-can-i-add-an-empty-directory-to-a-git-repository)

Comment: Is it your intent to include the content in the same repo?  Because to me that output suggests that you may have the directories configured as submodules

Comment: Folders are not empty. And yes, I think they are (or actually "were" until I removed the .git directory from them I think) submodules.

Answer (score 6):

The long answer above is great but the TL;DR to fix it is:

1. remove the .git repo of the sub-repo
2. Run `git rm -r --cached .`
3. Run `git add .`

then `git status` should show you the folder added

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you see:

```
modified: some-name (modified content)
```

in `git status` output, this means that *your* Git repository thinks that the directory named `some-name` is part of some *other* Git repository.  (Note that the sub-directory / folder name here, `some-name` in this example, *does not* end with a slash.)

One way that I find helpful to think about this issue is to pretend that there are multiple Gits involved (because there are): one is *your* Git, working in your repository, and the other in this case is the folder or subdirectory's Git, working in this second Git repository.  And it is—or at least *was*—a second Git repository, at some point.

This bears repeating: this sub-directory / folder really *was* some other Git repository before.  It may or may not *still* be a second repository.  Moreover, **your own Git repository has already recorded the presence of the other Git in some way.**  If your Git repository had not recorded that, you would have seen:

```
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        subgit/
```

Instead, though, you are seeing:

```
Changes not staged for commit:
...
        modified:   subgit (modified content)
```

So, the fact that *your* Git repository's `git status` output says `modified content` or `untracked content` means *your* repository is *quite certain* that this sub-directory is some *other* repository.  Your repository is reporting the relative state of the *other* repository.

You can get another hint about this if you use `git status -uall`, or `git status --untracked-files=all` (these mean the same thing, `-u` is short for `--untracked-files=`): if your Git *doesn't* think the sub-directory contains another Git repository, it will look inside the sub-directory and tell you about *each file* in the directory.  If your Git is convinced that the sub-directory is a Git repository of its own, it *won't* look inside it and report each file—but your Git also won't say "modified content" or "untracked content" like this.

## What to do about this depends on what you want to happen in the end

First, we need to talk about submodules.

#### Submodules

Git has a concept called *submodules*.  Some people call them *sob-modules* because they make programmers cry.  A submodule essentially means: *I tell my Git to record information about another Git repository.*

Now, think about the way you clone a Git repository.  It's with one simple command: `git clone url name`, or maybe even just `git clone url` with the resulting clone going into a directory/folder name based on the URL.  (Giving the *`name`* argument picks the directory/folder name instead of letting the URL dictate it.)

So, if your repository—which we'll call the *superproject* since it supervises some sub-Gits—is going to refer to some *other* repository, what your Git is going to need is:

- the URL it should clone
- the directory/folder name it should use when cloning

These two pieces of information are, in a *proper* submodule, stored in a file named `.gitmodules` in the top level of the superproject.

This `.gitmodules` file is needed to make a *new* clone of the superproject.  It's only needed in a *new* clone!  If you already have a clone, that's working and is managing its sub-repositories, the contents of the `.gitmodules` file *don't matter any more.*

#### With or without `.gitmodules`, your Git also records more *about* the submodule

Every Git repository has three parts:

1. Git stores the `.git` repository itself.  This contains a couple of databases that you don't need to poke around in yourself.
2. Git also stores something called, variously, the *index*, the *staging area*, or the *cache*.  What it's called depends on who or which part of Git is doing the calling, but all three are names for the same thing.
3. Git provides for you a *work-tree*.  The files inside your Git repository are stored in a special, frozen, compressed, Git-only format.  They can't be *changed*.  They can be *added-to*, as in adding more versions of files, but they're all just historical records.  So you need a place where you can get *at* those files, in ordinary non-Git format, and work on and with them.  That's your *work-tree*.

The work-tree is often the part of Git you work with the most—well, naturally, it's right there in the name, isn't it?  And yet, Git doesn't really *use* the work-tree, in a sense.  It puts files into it, for you to use; and when you run `git add`, your Git copies files *out* of the work-tree, into that thing in #2 above: they go into the *index*.

When Git makes a *new* commit, Git uses the files that are in the *index*.  It's the presence of a file *in* the index that makes a file *tracked* in the first place.  When you have Git fill in your work-tree, using `git checkout` to extract a commit, Git first fills in your *index*.  All of the real Git action is taking place in this index: existing commits go into it, and new commits are made from it.  So it's the index, not the work-tree, that really matters, at least as far as new commits go.  No matter what you do in the work-tree, Git only really pays attention to the index.  **This is why you have to keep using `git add` all the time: it's the copy of each file *in* the index that matters to Git.**

In short, your index holds what will go into the *next commit you make*.  It has inside it a copy of *all* of your files, in the pre-Git-ified, ready-to-freeze forever format.  That's what makes your index so crucial.  If you change a work-tree file you must use `git add` to copy (and Git-ify) the file to be ready for the next commit.

So, for Git, what matters are *commits*, identified by their big ugly hash IDs—which are unique: no two different commits ever have the same hash ID—and the *index* that it uses to make *new* commits.  You use the work-tree to do your work, but then you update your Git's index and have your Git make a new commit from it.

This is where submodules come in again, too.  If your Git is acting as a superproject, supervising some sub-Git in some folder named `subgit/` for instance, then *your* Git will record *their* Git's commit hash ID, in your index!

Think about that for a while.  Your Git doesn't save their Git's files.  Your Git knows that if their Git—the Git in your `subgit/` folder—has saved some files in a commit, that commit hash ID is good *forever*.  That one simple hash ID, big and ugly as it may be, uniquely identifies *all those files, in their saved-forever form*.  So your Git does not *need* to save the files.  All it has to do is save their commit's hash ID.

That's exactly what your superproject Git does.  Instead of saving files—their files—your Git just saved their *commit hash ID*, in your index.  And then, since it's in your index, it goes into your commits, too.  *From this point forward, every new commit you make contains their hash ID.*  If you want to record a *different* hash ID, you tell them—the other Git, the one in control of the `subgit/` folder—to switch to a different commit hash ID, or to make a whole new commit; and then you have *your* Git record that hash ID in your index, so that your *next* commit has the right subproject hash ID.

**Note that all of this works even without a `.gitmodules` file.**  But if you don't have a `.gitmodules` file, this superproject that supervises some other Git repository works here, but you won't be able to clone it easily later.

## Now you must decide: do you want a submodule, or not?

If you *want* submodules, well, you're already there—or at least halfway there.  If you have a `.gitmodules` file that lists the subproject repository, your superproject already records the correct URL and name for future clones.  If not, you should probably create a `.gitmodules` file, using `git submodule add`.  See also [How to `git submodule add` Existing sub Repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32776018/1256452)  (This answers the question of how to fix up a subproject repository that wasn't added properly originally, but that you *do* want to use as a proper submodule.)

#### So you want a submodule, and already have it in `.gitmodules`

Given that you have decided that you *do* want to use a submodule, and that it's all correctly recorded, what you need to do now is *not* `git add subgit`.  As you already saw, that doesn't do anything!

Instead, what you need to do is to start a new session—by `cd`-ing into the submodule, or opening a new window in which you start working in the submodule, or whatever.  Now you're in a new and different repository!  But, uh oh, you're probably in *detached HEAD* mode.

That's OK: you can choose to work in this mode.  Or, you can run `git checkout somebranch` to get on some branch, or `git checkout -b newbranch` to create a *new* branch at the current commit.  You should do whatever makes sense for *this* Git repository.

Now that you are in this new and different repository, you can work as usual, with your work-tree.  Once you have all the files arranged the way you want, on the branch you want, you will `git add` modified files and/or `git add` untracked files to copy them into the index.  You then `git commit` the result.  And now you have a new commit, and you can `git push` it or whatever it is that you do with these commits in *this* repository.

Now that you're done making the new commit that holds the updated and/or new files in the subproject, *now* you can go back to the superproject.  You `cd` back to the superoject, or close this window, or whatever, and resume work in the superproject.

Now all you have to do in the superproject is run `git add subproject`.  If the subproject is named `subgit`, just `git add subgit`.  That copies the sub-repository's *commit hash ID* into your *index*, so now it's ready to commit.  Add anything else you like, and run `git commit` to make a new commit that freezes all your index contents forever.  That saves *your* files, and your subproject's *commit hash ID*, all of which were ready to go in your index.

#### So you don't want a submodule or subgit at all

This one is a little harder, especially in very old versions of Git.  Modern Git makes it much easier.  So here I'm going to outsource the entire answer to [How do I remove a submodule?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1260748/1256452)  Note that most of the answers, including [this short one for modern Git](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36593218/1256452), have the idea that you're also going to remove the entire *work-tree* of the sub-repository.  If you want to *keep* the work-tree, the simplest method is just to move or copy it somewhere else.  **Be sure to save the files that are modified and/or untracked**, since they're probably not *in* any commit in the sub-repository!

Comment: Dear torek, thanks for your very detailed answer. I guess I will have to read it very carefully to understand the subtleties involved with the submodules concept.