# How to commit correctly as normal

Tags: git

I have just initialized a web project which contains two folders: 'client' initialized by create-react-app and 'server' initialized by express.Then I run `git init` in the root content and then `git add .` and `git commit ...` as usual. Here comes the problem:   the changes in source control showed me that 'client' contains emphasized items and no matter how many times I do the commit or discard ths changes showed about 'client', seems like it has always been there.When I pushed the commit to my remote repository, the client folder is empty. After the first push, every time I tried to push again the cmd just show `Changes not staged for commit:
        modified:   client (modified content, untracked content)`, So what's wrong with the 'client' folder? I really didn't do anything after initializing...

Comment: When you do `git add .`, just check the files and folders are getting staged using `git status`.

Comment: Looks like `client` is a submodule.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git: How to commit untracked content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54902890/git-how-to-commit-untracked-content)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+modified+content+untracked+content

Answer (score -2):

```
git init
git add .
git remote add origin 'urlofrepository'
git commit -m 'first commit'
git push -u origin master
```